# Strategy to sort html content for writing

Tags: javascript, sorting

I've got a general question about a strategy for sorting html elements. Here's the prereqs:

I'm dynamically building content that will get written to an HTML file. This content is written to a string that will subsequently be saved to the body of an html file. The content consists of a hierarchical representation of ul and li tags, for example (coded here with spaces and on separate lines for clarity)

```
var mText = "<ul>";
mText += "<li class='folder'>folder 1";
mText += "   <ul>";
mText += "      <li class='page'>page 3</li>";
mText += "      <li class='page'>page 2</li>";
mText += "      <li class='folder'>sub folder 2";
mText += "         <ul>";
mText += "            <li class='page'>sub page 3</li>";
mText += "            <li class='page'>sub page 1</li>";
mText += "         </ul>";
mText += "      </li>";
mText += "      <li class='folder'>sub folder 1";
mText += "         <ul>";
mText += "            <li class='page'>sub page 5</li>";
mText += "            <li class='page'>sub page 4</li>";
mText += "         </ul>";
mText += "      </li>";
mText += "   </ul>";
mText += "</li>";
mText += "</ul>";
```

So I end up with a string representation of the elements I want to write (consider that pseudo-code if you find typos or other discrepancies). There may be more levels in the hierarchy.

Now, I need to sort that, by folder name, or file name, or both. This string is constructed from a hierarchy (a linked list) of objects (associative arrays) so sorting before converting that structure to text presents similar issues... and I am trying to figure out whether or not it would be easier to sort before conversion to the string or after.

How would I go about doing that as is? convert that to a multi-dimensional array, sort the array and then convert back to a string representation?  Or is there some way I could sort the contents of the string?

I'm no novice to javascript, and understand sorting - that's no problem - but I'm just looking for general directions, and thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with sorting the arrays prior to string conversion.  Performance will be much better as sorting an array of objects is much lighter than rearranging the contents of a string (especially a very large string).

Also just as an aside when you are doing a large amount string concatenation operations you should use the array method:

```
var mText = new Array();
mText.push("<li class='folder'>folder 1");
mText.push("   <ul>");
mText.push("      <li class='page'>page 3</li>");
mText.push("      <li class='page'>page 2</li>");
mText.push("      <li class='folder'>sub folder 2");
mText.push("         <ul>");
mText.push("            <li class='page'>sub page 3</li>");
mText.push("            <li class='page'>sub page 1</li>");
mText.push("         </ul>");
mText.push("      </li>";");
mText.push("      <li class='folder'>sub folder 1");
mText.push("         <ul>");
mText.push("            <li class='page'>sub page 5</li>");
mText.push("            <li class='page'>sub page 4</li>");
mText.push("         </ul>");
mText.push("      </li>");
mText.push("   </ul>");
mText.push("</li>");
mText.push("</ul>");

//this will create the final string
return mText.join("");
```

This will be much faster than the "+=" method in most cases.

Comment: you missed my note: that's pseudo-code for clarity only! That aside,  there is no way to sort javascript objects, so I have to convert the objects to arrays, but building that text is more convenient from the linked list of objects already created, so I think it ends up  being more convenient in the end to sort after the fact.  Performance is not an issue in my context.

Comment: You may want to checkout this: http://www.latentmotion.com/how-to-sort-an-associative-array-object-in-javascript/ .  It has a method for sorting Associative Arrays.

Comment: sure, you can sort arrays of objects, but my initially built representation is not an array of object, it is in object properties ('associative arrays') - it is a linked list of objects representing a file tree.  I am not using arrays to build the tree because of the way the page and folder data is being given to me, I have to do a lot of cross referencing to recursively construct the tree representation. Using object properties makes that cross referencing a snap - using arrays would be a major chore.

Comment: it is my understanding that there is no way to guarantee any specific order when iterating over object properties, no matter how you try to sort them. I've seen that in many javascript references...

Answer (score 0):

can you use the DOM methods such as `document.CreateElement` instead of creating the string manually? I think that would make it much easier to sort.

Comment: Only real reason to go with string concatenation over the DOM creation method is performance.  Typically building the markup in a string will be faster than building a DOM tree to insert into a page.  Both are valid just have different performance characteristics.

Comment: yeah, I thought about that, but these are not dom elements to begin with - they are being pulled from a database of pages and folders names (including their relationships), so I get them as text, construct a linked list (tree) javascript representation of that data, and then build a text representation of the HTML from that...

Comment: I suppose I could add the text sting to an html element using jQuery, then sort, and then get the result back into a string...?